# What's the RPG where one character class acts as a “conduit” or “catalyst” for the others' “spells”?

Tags: product-identification, darksword-adventures

I'm looking for the identity of an RPG I remember reading in paperback book form (rather a thick tome), must have been published late 80s–early 90s.

A distinguishing feature was that while many (or in fact nearly all?) character “classes”* had specific magical/psionic abilities, they all depended on a further class of characters whose only role was to “enable” aforementioned “casters”. I think the enablers were called conduits or catalysts.

<sup>* Please excuse the heavy use of quote marks. I'm not sure of the exact terminology and I remember that the background actually avoided typical fantasy/sci-fi nomenclature (maybe that's another distinguisher if I remember rightly!)</sup>

Comment: Was this book written in english? Do you remember any other details about the setting or the book?

Comment: Definitely English. I don't remember anything else... Maybe more of a long shot than I imagined.

Comment: This was a standard quality trade paperback from the library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not remember an RPG built on it, but this definitely sounds like the [*Darksword* saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksword) to me.

After some search, perhaps I found the game you remember: [*Darksword Adventures*](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=3277).

> Unusually, a game in the format of a paperback novel. *Darksword Adventures* shares a setting with the four Darksword books by the same authors. It is a fantasy setting where magic is Life and those without it are outcasts. Your status in the world is strictly determined by the nature and power of your magic.

Comment: Thanks Matteo, this sounds like the very thing. I had no idea who Hickman and Weiss were at the time! Now it sorta makes sense they were behind this.

Comment: Just to be clear: @Matteo Tassarinari hit the nail on the head. I bought a copy of the book and it's even better than I remember. Thanks!